# Lambda expression select and add

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am trying to select and add to list using lambda.can some body help me where I am making mistake.Below code gives me compile error.

```
string Param = "param1=test;param2=test2;param3=test3";
List<SqlParameter> param=new List<SqlParameter>();
var ef = d.Select(x => x.Split('='))
          .Select(y => new { id = y[0], val = y[1] })
          .Select(z=>sqlparam.Add(new SqlParameter(z.id, (object)z.val)));
```

Comment: What is `d`?  You don't show it in your example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not clear why you're trying to use `Select` for this, but it's not working because `List<T>.Add` has a `void` return method, and the lambda expression you use in a projection has to return the value you're projecting to. I suggest you use:

```
string param = "param1=test;param2=test2;param3=test3";
var parameters = d.Select(x => x.Split('='))
                  .Select(y => new { id = y[0], val = y[1] })
                  .Select(z => new SqlParameter(z.id, (object)z.val)))
                  .ToList();
```

(Note how spreading the statement over multiple lines also makes it much simpler to read than having one very long line.)

Comment: Thx john.It works.is there a way can I add to parameter collection with out select

Comment: @user2107843: Do you mean to a `SqlParameterCollection` (rather than to a `List<SqlParameter>`? I'd just use a `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Select to iterate your collections? It seems more readable to use a simple loop.

```
string paramString = "param1=test;param2=test2;param3=test3";    
IEnumerable<string[]> parameters = paramString.Split(';').Select(y => y.Split('='));

List<SqlParameter> sqlParams = new List<SqlParameter>();

foreach (string[] parameter in parameters)
{
    sqlParams.Add(new SqlParameter(parameter[0], parameter[1]));
}

Console.WriteLine(sqlParams);
```